# Using NFS with external drives

Tags: external-disk, mount, nfs

I am trying to share an external drive using NFS with other machines on my network, but encountering a stale file handle that I can't seem to get rid of.

I have tried the following in my `etc/exports`

```
/Volumes/Foo -ro -mapall=nobody -fsuuid=[uuid]
```

Where [uuid] is the actual id (confirmed to match, because if it doesn't, `nfsd checkexports` will complain).  On the client side, when I do `showmount -e [serverhostname]`, I see

```
/Volumes/Foo            Everyone
```

When mounting via `mount_nfs [serverhostname]:/Volumes/Foo bar`, I'm told that the it was not possible due to a stale file handle.  I've tried a number of the general trouble shooting fixes for stale file handles (reset server, remove entry, reset, then readd, unmount on client, etc) but none of them seem to work.

Mounting shares on the main drive works without any problem, it's just the one on the external that is causing issues.

I'm running fresh installs of 10.15.6 on host and client.

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running?

Comment: @nohillside 10.15.6 on host and client.  I've updated the Q